# order of objects with phrasal verbs (e.g "put on")

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs, indirect-objects

Let's take the phrasal verb "put sth on" in the meaning "to cover part of the body with clothes". Having the direct object only (as a pronoun), the sentence is:

> I put it on.

Now, I want to add the indirect object "you". I want to express that the person I'm speaking to is covered with `it` by me.

What is/are the right sentence(s) to express that?

> I put you it on.
>   I put it you on.
>   I put it on you.

I would be great if you could add a couple of other examples of sentences with phrasal verbs and two objects (direct object as pronoun), where the indirect object is not marked by an own adposition (preposition or postposition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I put it on you" is the only possible one of your three versions, though it would be more natural to say "I put your coat on for you" or "I help you into your coat".

We could say "Here's another blanket. Shall I put it over you?"

"No-one can take it from you."

Is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: "I put it on (you)." is what I wanted, thx. Other examples: I noticed that my request was not precise enough. All ex. given by you have a preposition ("over", "from") clearly marking the role of the indirect object "you". What I really wanted, are examples w/o such a preposition. In case of non-phrasal verbs, it would be: "Simone gave him a dirty look"/"Simone gave him it" or "I'll tell them the story"/"I'll tell them it"; just with phrasal verbs. But I'm not sure if such phrasal verbs (=verbs with two objects, indirect not marked by an adposition) even exist in English, except of "put on".

Comment: "She gave him it" and "I'll tell them it" are understandable but sound very awkward; it would be usual to say "She gave it to him", "I'll tell it to them".

Comment: That's very interesting. Stringing a pronoun after another one is not idiomatic in English. - You're right. Let's skip this kind of sentences. I've removed the restriction for the indirect object to be a pronoun. I just want the direct object to be a pronoun because with phrasal verbs they always go between the main word of the verb and the particle. So, I'm looking for examples like "Simone gave him a dirty look" or "I'll tell them the story"; just with phrasal verbs; just with phrasal verbs and no marking adposition for the indirect object. - Are there any such phrasal verbs at all?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can't think of any.